# Cant connect to mysql: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

I'm start to learn mysql not so long time ago, and now i have problem, that i cant solve by myself.
I'm trying to connect to mysql server with php. My admin gaved me ip, port, login, pass and db name.
Php file looks like this:

```
$hostname = '192.168.1.20:1433';
$username = "h";
$password = "h";
$dbName = "mydb";
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM `insy` WHERE 1;";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "works!";
mysql_close();
```

When i run page, its do nothing few minutes, than errors appears:
    Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=1908 in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12
MySQL server has gone away
```

12'th line is:

```
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

I tried to create ODBC Sql Server via Control Panel -> Administration - with same parameters - it works, connection is ok, and i ca see the Db's.

Tell me please, where is my fault?
I hope, i was clear.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Any recent changes to the server? Read over the [gone away documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: If you're just learning MySQL, don't start with at the old mysql_* functions. Learn mysqli and get it right from the start. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Answer (score 1):

you can try `mysql_ping($conn)` if your server connection lost.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved that problem.. the thing was when I did create a new user in MySql, after writing the user, the server ask you for where will be the "server" and you put localhost:8080.. ERROR! don't put the port!! just localhost. 
And thats how I solved it..

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a port other than the default `3306`.
Define the port number under within the hostname like so:

`$hostname = '192.168.1.20:your_port_number';`

Otherwise use:

`$hostname = 'localhost';`